# esm package with mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

Since I updated my npm package for use with Node v12 it isn't necessary to transpile the sources with babel for production use. All of the ES6 features, we use, are now supported by node. That's fine. I would be even happier, if I could now use mocha without babel. It works fine with:

```
NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --watch --require babel-core/register --watch-extensions js,json -t 10000
```

Internet says, mocha can handle ES6 code with the esm package. So I did:

```
npm i esm --save-dev
```

and changed the mocha command to

```
NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --watch --require esm --watch-extensions js,json -t 10000
```

But I still get the error message:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I think that's because mocha still interprets the source as common JS.

How can I tell mocha to use ES6 (or higher)?